# Lambda function in accumulate

Tags: c++, lambda, accumulate

I'm trying to learn how to use lamba functions, and want to do something like:

Given a vector = {1,2,3,4,5}

I want the sum of pairwise sums = (1+2)+(2+3)+...

Below is my attempt, which is not working properly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector <double> data = {1,10,100};

double mean = accumulate(data.begin(),data.end(),0.0);

double foo()
{
    auto bar = accumulate(data.begin(),data.end(),0.0,[&](int k, int l){return (k+l);});

    return bar
}
```

I tried changing the return statement to return (data.at(k)+data.at(l)), which didn't quite work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding pairwise sums is the same as summing over everything twice except the first and last elements. No need for a fancy lambda.

```
auto result = std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 0.0)
  * 2.0 - data.front() - data.end();
```

Or a little safer:

```
auto result = std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 0.0) 
   * 2.0 - (!data.empty() ? data.front() : 0) - (data.size() > 1 ? data.back() : 0);
```

If you insist on a lambda, you can move the doubling inside:

```
result = std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 0.0, 
   [](double lhs, double rhs){return lhs + 2.0*rhs;}) 
   - data.front() - data.back();
```

Note that `lhs` within the lambda is the *current sum*, not the next two numbers in the sequence.

If you insist on doing all the work within the lambda, you can track an index by using [generalized capture](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures):

```
result = std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), 0.0, 
       [currIndex = 0U, lastIndex = data.size()-1] (double lhs, double rhs) mutable
       {
          double result = lhs + rhs;
          if (currIndex != 0 && currIndex != lastIndex)
             result += rhs;
          ++currIndex;
          return result;
       });
```

[Demo of all approaches](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0a8b111ec760dcc)

Comment: Hah, some theoretical physicist I am not coming up with the elegant solution in your first paragraph! Then there is indeed no need for _fancy lambda_.  Also props for demos and still writing a solution using lambda, which I probably wont need now, but it's instructive!

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how `std::accumulate` works. Let's say you have `int array[]`, then accumulate does:

```
int value = initial_val;
value = lambda( value, array[0] );
value = lambda( value, array[1] );
...
return value;
```

this is pseudo code, but it should be pretty easy to understand how it works. So in your case `std::accumulate` does not seem to be applicable. You may write a loop, or create your own special `accumulate` function:

```
auto lambda = []( int a, int b ) { return a + b; };
auto sum = 0.0;
for( auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it ) {
    auto itn = std::next( it );
    if( itn == data.end() ) break;
    sum += lambda( *it, *itn );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a working code using a `for` loop already, I just thought that it could all be captured more neatly using `accumulate` and that ,if I wanted to use `accumulate`, I needed to a lambda function to specify the binary operator. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You could capture a variable in the lambda to keep the last value:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

std::vector<double> data = {1,10,100};

double mean = accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0);

double foo()
{
    double last{0};
    auto bar = accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0, [&](auto k, auto l) 
    {
        auto total = l + last; 
        last = l; 
        return total+k; 
    });

    return bar;
}

int main()
{
    auto val = foo();
}
```

Comment: I didn't now you could capture last, that's actually very useful, thanks!

Comment: Maybe rename variable 'mean' to 'sum' ? Or, include a division by data.size() ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some sort of index, and add the next number.

```
size_t index = 1;
auto bar = accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0, [&index, &data](double a, double b) {
    if (index < data.size())
        return a + b + data[index++];
    else 
        return a + b;
});
```

Note you have a vector of `double`s but are using `int`s to sum.